# Is there any database solution that can do master-master replication by default on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, database, rc

There are many "built-in" softwares for OpenBSD, ex.: NTP, LDAP, RADIUS, etc., see all (?):

https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/etc/rc.conf

in the rc.conf file.

**The question**: Currently, 2017 Dec, I cannot find any database software by default, is this true?

I know I can install several from the ports, but I am searching one that is shipped with the base (and even knows master-master replication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no database software (in the conventional sense) included in the OpenBSD base installation.  SQLite was part of the base system, but that too has been put back into the ports system [with the release of 6.1](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/upgrade61.html).

The OpenBSD developers are unlikely to include any software in the base system that is "big" unless it's actually *used* by the base system.  Most database solutions are too big and complicated to meet the OpenBSD criteria of simple and secure.

---

SQLite was removed in 6.1 since [mandoc.db(5)](http://man.openbsd.org/mandoc.db) no longer needed it.